# Inline expression using for and if loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the question:

```
input = array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5])
```

Required output: any value `> 1` should be set to `1`

```
array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1])
```

My current program

```
import numpy as np

input = np.arange(0,2,0.5);#array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5])  

for i in np.arange(0, np.size(input)):  
    if input[i] > 1:
        input[i] = 1
```

What is the short form for this simple operation:

```
dummy3 =[if i> 1: xxxxxx , for i in input] 
or 
output = [if (for i in input) > 1: return 1 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output = [1 if i > 1 else i for i in input]
```

It's called [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

This create a new list that populate (conceptually) like this:

```
output = []
for i in input:
    if i > 1:
        output.append(1)
    else:
        output.append(i)
```

As mentioned in the comments, when you use `numpy` and want to change the original array you can do:

```
input[input>1]=1
```

Comment: Code only answer? Provide *some* explanation.

Comment: Just added some link

Comment: Thanks Ohad. Can I ask why 1 is appearing at the first. If i remove it, it is giving syntax error :(   

Got it, it is to say the output from if loop, if the condition of i >1 is followed.  I am trying to find any possible link from python, in which they showed this kind of coding habits. Anyway it solved my issue.

Comment: @OhadEytan explain the actual code and take time to write a thorough answer. Posts like these are considered low-quality as they are mostly code and a link. Provide more explanation.

Comment: @AndrewL. this is a basic concept in python, It doesn't make sense to explain all of it any time. Nevertheless I added some explanation to how it works.

Comment: @learner123 while this is a correct answer for normal lists - it misses the fact that you're using a `numpy.array`... what you're actually after here is `a[a > 1] = 1`...

Comment: @JonClements added your solution :)

Comment: Jon, a[a > 1] = 1 is super short. However I don't want to overwrite a. is there any another way like ?

Comment: @JonClements, thats great. Thanks a ton.